# how to check there is a row in specific index to avoid IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, datatable, indexoutofrangeexception

I want to to know how to check there is a row in specific index to avoid the following exception :

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

for example :

```
if (dtNew != null && dtNew.Rows.Count > 0 )
{
    if (dtNew.Rows[i][0] != null)
    {
        row["newEmp"] = dtNew.Rows[i][0];
    }
    else
    {
        row["newEmp"] = 0;
    }
}
```

What if `dtNew` has just `a one row` and the `i = 3` !!

Comment: Can you use Contains method?

Comment: iterate over it using ``Count`` of it

Comment: the loop has more than datatable wiz different counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to get to row `i`, you need to change your check from

```
&& dtNew.Rows.Count > 0
```

to

```
&& dtNew.Rows.Count > i
```

Currently you're only checking whether there are *any* rows - i.e. whether `dtNew.Rows[0]` is valid.

(Do you definitely need to check for `dtNew` being `null`? Is that a valid program state? Likewise is it valid for the row to exist but column 0 to not be populated? You may be able to make your code much simpler.)